# Does the Epic Loremaster learn new spells if he attains a new level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, epic-tier

According to the SRD, about the Epic [Loremaster](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/loremaster.htm):

> The epic loremaster’s caster level increases by 1 for each new loremaster level she attains. If she has more than one spellcasting class, she must decide which class receives the increase in caster level. The epic loremaster’s number of spells per day (and number of spells known, if applicable) *does not **automatically** increase* after 10th level.

Source: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/prestigeClassProgressions.htm#epicLoremaster

This *automatically* means that a Epic Loremaster doesn't get new daily spells when increasing their Loremaster level, regarding of his basic spellcaster class, or that he'll only increase his daily spell slots if his basic spellcaster class is below the 20th class level?

For example, a Wizard 5/Rogue 5/Loremaster 10 cast spells as a Wizard 15; so, if when reaching 21th level he gets a new Loremaster level (becoming a Loremaster 11, so this will be an epic Loremaster level). According to the SRD, his caster level will increase, but do his daily spell slots increase too, since he still doesn't have the daily spells of a Wizard 20?

P.s.: I'm not interested if it's a good idea to get epic Loremaster levels, I just want to know how the rules work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant class feature in the Loremaster prestige class is

> **Spells per Day/Spells Known**
>
> When a new loremaster level is gained, ***the character gains new spells per day (and spells known, if
> applicable) as if she had also gained a level in a spellcasting class
> she belonged to before she added the prestige class***. She does not,
> however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have
> gained. This essentially means that she adds the level of loremaster
> to the level of some other spellcasting class the character has, then
> determines ***spells per day***, ***spells known***, and ***caster level*** accordingly.

By gaining a level of Loremaster you get (among other things)

- To increase your caster level to your Loremaster level plus original
  spell caster level.
- To cast more spells as if you are that level of caster.

The Epic rules for Loremaster clearly deactivates the second benefit once you progress beyond 10th level Loremaster. So in your example, that character can only cast a number of spells equal to that of a 15th level Wizard no matter how many additional Loremaster levels he will gain.

Comment: This is the most obvious reading of that rule. However, the word "automatically" is what bugs me. I suppose this means that I can "manually" increase the daily spell slots when attaining a Loremaster level using the feat [Improved Spell Capacity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/feats.htm#improvedSpellCapacity) or other mechanism. 
Or I can simply get Wizard levels

Comment: @BrianHellekin, my opinion is that the rule in the Epic Loremaster is referring only to class feature of the original prestige class. Using feats or adding Wizard levels is not covered by that so offers an alternate path to increase the number of spells you cast as an Epic level character

Comment: @RS_Conley, yes, it was I wanted to say, that you still can increase your daily spells using these feats, but not by simply attaining a new Loremaster level,